# Не работает printf в цикле

Tags: c

Есть программа, которая ищет длину максимальной подпоследовательности двух строк, а потом выводит саму подпоследовательность. Проблема в том, что у меня не работает ни один printf, начиная со строчки char S[1001] = ".";. Помогите найти ошибку.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int max(int a, int b){
    if (a >= b){
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}

void lcs_length(char A[1001], char B[1001]) {

    int m = strlen(A);
    int n = strlen(B);
    int L[m][n]; 
    int i, j;

    for (i = m; i >= 0; i--, putchar('\n')) {
        for (j = n; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (A[i] == '\0' || B[j] == '\0') {
                L[i][j] = 0;

            }
            else if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                L[i][j] = 1 + L[i+1][j+1];

            }
            else { 
                L[i][j] = max(L[i+1][j], L[i][j+1]);
            }
            printf ("%d", L[i][j]);
        }
    }
//  printf("%d", L[0][0]);


    char S[1001] = ".";
    int q = 0;
    int w = 0;
    while (q < m && w < n) {
        if (A[q] == B[w]) {
            printf("%s", A[q]);
            strcat(S, &A[q]);
            q++; w++;
        }
        else if (A[q+1] == B[w]) {
            q++;
        }
        else if (A[q] == B[w+1]) {
            w++;
        }
        else if (L[q+1][w] >= L[q][w+1]){
            q++;
        }
        else {
            w++;
        }

    }

    printf(S);
}

void main() {
    char A[1001] = "BDCABA";
    char B[1001] = "ABCBDAB";
    lcs_length(A, B);

}
```

Comment: А `int L[m][n];` вообще работает? Помнится мне, нельзя объявлять массив так, если `m` и `n` не константы

Comment: Да, это работает. С кодом ДО цикла while проблем нет

Comment: `printf("%s", A[q]);` - `A[q]` у вас ведь `char`, а не `char*`. Но у вас еще выход за пределы массива (например, `L[i][j]` при `i==m` и `j==n`, не говоря уж о `L[i+1][j+1]`). Ну и у вас, как по мне, проблемы со стеком - уж очень много вы в него засовываете... Ограничьтесь, например, не 1001 - а 20, и `printf("%s", A[q]);` замените на `printf("%с", A[q]);` и посмотрите, что получится...

Comment: @V-Mor: Это вопрос по языку С.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в управляющей последовательности `printf`.

1. Чтобы вывести **строку**, необходимо передать `"%s"` и **указатель**
   на начало нуль-терминированной строки
2. Чтобы вывести  **символ**, необходимо передать `"%c"` и сам символ

Предлагаю исправить `printf("%s", A[q]);` на `printf("%c", A[q]);`

P.S. Я всё ещё в недоумении от того, что у Вас работает это:

```c
int m = strlen(A);
int n = strlen(B);
int L[m][n];
```

Comment: «*Я всё ещё в недоумении от того, что у Вас работает это*». Так VLA же.

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо, как-то я упустил это. И Visual Studio, по-моему, тоже ("выражение должно иметь константное значение" – говорит мне VS2017)

Comment: Ну, начиная с C11 реализации не обязаны поддерживать VLA. Возможно, вы компилируете именно в режиме C11, тогда надо смотреть на `__STDC_NO_VLA__`.

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо, учту.